# no module named numpy despite numpy being already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda

i get this error when running a python script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BruceWayne\Desktop\TF\train.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

So i tried

```
pip install numpy
```

and the answer was that the requirement is already satisfied